# JMeter: How to insert the parameters in an HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, parameters, get, jmeter

I have been using JMeter for a few weeks now, and have recently run into a problem trying to insert parameters into an API request that I am testing.

When I set up the basic GET HTTP request, using the end point below:

```
https://www.blahSite.com/blahReport/reportDates?q=start_date::2017-01-01|end_date::2017-05-23
```

I get the following error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 90: https://www.blahsite.com/blahReport/reportDates?q=start_date::2017-01-01|end_date::2017-05-23
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:357)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried setting up the parameters to send with reqeust, located directly below the textfield for the Path, but I get the following JSON error when I try to use them:

```
{"status":"error","message":"Invalid parameter start_date","code":30000}
```

I assume I am missing some step that is probably obvious to more experienced users, but I haven't been able to find an answer within the manual, or any of the various youtube videos I've watched.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

figured out what I was doing wrong.

I was listing each date(start & end) as its own parameter.

I needed to list the parameter as "q", with the string containing start and end date as the value

so instead of:

```
**Parameter**       **Value**
start_date          2017-01-01
end_date            2017-05-23
```

it should have been:

```
**Parameter**       **Value**
q                   start_date::2017-01-01|end_date::2017-05-23
```

hopefully this helps someone with a similar problem.